# Slick mapping between table rows and domain, usual solution

Tags: slick, slick-2.0

What is the usual/recommended way to transform the table mapped classes to the more complex domain object ?

```
package slick
case class Folder(id:Long, name:String)
case class File(id:Long, name:String, folder:Option[Long])

package domain
case class Folder(name:String, parent:Option[Folder], childrens:Set[File])
case class File(name:String)
```

With plain old Java apps, I'm used to have a set of *daos* (the slick `Table`) and a conversion layer who use those *daos* to map and build the object graph. But I hope that Slick can provide better alternatives.

Thanks